# Empty String Check - EL Notation

Tags: jsf, el, seam

I'm new to JSF and EL but why doesn't this work?

```
<c:if test="#{not empty user.link}">
    <div class="userLink">
          <a href="#{user.link}">
            <img src="img/usericon.png" width="75" height="auto"/>
          </a>
    </div>
</c:if>
```

Even though the string is never empty, the image never gets displayed. I've tried user.link.length() gt 0, user.link.length > 0, user.link != null, not user.link eq null, etc, etc. Nothing seems to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you verify that the string is not empty? Try putting a breakpoint in the getter to verify the value returned.

Comment: Thanks Meriton. Ugh, how embarrassing. Yep. I was out-jecting a new object and at that point wasn't resetting the value so it was null by the time it was getting to the UI.